# No shortcut : save dict to file / count items in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Python 3

Hello guys I'm a python beginner studying dictionary now

below is what I have learned so far how to save list into a file

and count items in list like below.

```
class item:
    name = None
    score = None

def save_list_in_file(file_name:str, L:[item]):
    f = open(file_name,'w')
    for it in L:
        f.write(it.name + "" + str(it.score))
    f.close()

def count_item_in_list(L:[item])->int:
    n = 0
    for it in L:
        if it.score >= 72:
        n += 1
    return n
```

and I'm not sure if using dictionary is same way as I use in list

for example:

```
def save_dict_to_file(file_name:str, D:{item}):
    f = open(file_name,'w')
    for it in D:
        f.write(it.name + "" + str(it.score))
    f.close()

def count_item_in_dict(D:{item})->int:
    n = 0
    for it in D:
        if it.score <= 72:
        n += 1
    return n
```

will be correct? i thought dict would be different than using a list.

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: oops No shortcut means I'm not allowed to use simple modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a dictionary the same way as using a list.

A list is defined as a sequence of elements. So when you have the list:

```
    L=['D','a','v','i','d']
```

You can loop it like this:

```
    for it in L:
        print(it)
```

And it will print:

```
  D
  a
  v
  i
  d
```

Instead, a dictionary is a group of tuples of two elements where one is the key and the second is the value. So for example you have a Dictonary like this:

```
    D = {'firstletter' : 'D', 'secondletter': 'a', 'thirdletter' : 'v' }
```

And when you loop it like a list:

```
    for it in L:
        print(it)
```

it will print only the keys:

```
    firstletter
    secondletter
    thirdletter
```

so in order to obtain the values you have to print it like this:

```
    for it in D:
        print(D[it])
```

that will display this result:

```
D
a
v
```

If you need more information you can check de documentation for dictionary :)

[Python 3 documentation of Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)